# Where does a custom sql statement go in a code first entity framework project

Tags: entity-framework

Where does a custom sql statement go in a code first entity framework project?

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

It doesn't feel right placing it in a controller. So maybe in the IdentityModel.cs class?

Comment: Opinion based question I'm afraid.

Comment: Why isn't controller a right place? It's normal to access the context in the controller for CRUD operations. Custom SQL is not doing anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the strong positives of entity framework is that you seldom need to use SQL strings anymore. The disadvantage of the strings is that they can't be checked by the compiler and thus are error prone, especially after changing the database.

If you'd designed your classes according to the [Entity Framework Code First conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) your statement would be like:

```
using (var dbContext = new BloggingContext)
{
    // get all Blogs (note: very unusual!)
    var blogs = dbContext.Blogs.ToList();
}
```

Sometimes you need to explicitly use a SQL statement, for instance when calling a stored procedure. you could use object DbContext.Database:

```
using (var dbContext = new BloggingContext)
{
    string sqlCommand = ...
    Database database = dbContext.Database;
    database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand, <parameters>);
}
```

`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` uses the traditional method of querying databases.